# button data not showing up when using paypal javascript button

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons

i am testing out the paypal javascript button integration, and the button data is failing to show up. here is my code:

```
var data = {};
data['data-name'] = "donation";
data['data-amount'] = .99;
data['data-env'] = "sandbox";

var button = PAYPAL.apps.ButtonFactory.create("testuser@gmail.com", data, "donate");
$('.paypalbutton').append(button);
```

the donate button appears correctly, but when i click on it, the paypal start screen only displays the email, not the amount or the donation name.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

so as it turned out, the js object that the button factory create function was expecting was supposed to be formatted differently (it was expecting each parameter to be its own object with a value property);

also, you were apparently NOT supposed to prepend 'data-' to the button parameter names, despite what the documentation seemed to indicate.

unfortunately this was not documented anywhere, and i had to look at the paypal-button.js file to figure this out.

the working code looks like this:

```
var DataObject = {}; 

var Name = { "value" : "donation" };
var Amount = { "value" : "1.0" };
var Env = { "value" : "sandbox"};

DataObject["name"] = Name; 
DataObject["amount"] = Amount; 
DataObject["env"] = Env; 

var button = PAYPAL.apps.ButtonFactory.create("testuser@gmail.com", DataObject, "donate");
```

Answer (score 0):

I formatted the object like this:

```
var raw = { 
        environment: {"value" : "sandbox" },
        name: {"value" : "MindDecoder Credit" },
        amount: {"value" : val },
        tax: {"value" : vat },
        currency: {"value" : "EUR" },
        size: {"value" : "large" },
        lc: {"value" : "de_DE"}
        };
```

It seams a bit cleaner. Thank you very much for your answer @ilhashev, it helped me a ton!